# php modified array display values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$test = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
```

I unset two and four (because I really really dislike even numbers)

```
unset($test[array_search('two', $test)]);
unset($test[array_search('four', $test)]);
```

And am left with an array

```
$test = array(
[0] => 'one',
[2] => 'three',
[4] => 'five'
);
```

Now I need to loop through that array and obtain the value along with the correct key. I want to display

```
0 = one
2 = three
4 = five
```

What should I use to achieve that? I tried using standard

```
for($i=0; $i<count($test); $i++)
```

but that is not effective because it will loop and give me 0 1 2 instead of 0 2 4.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop for this

```
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Read about [foreach loop at](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) at php.net manual

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. I never knew that the $key would actually hold the value of the array element.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach ($test as $key => $value)`

Comment: Please don't post just code as an answer.  Code is great, but your answer will be more helpful if you describe why you suggest this code over other solutions, how you arrived at it, and how it works.

Comment: Ok. In this case I thought that the code will be enough, but I will heed your advice in future.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$len = count($test);
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i+=2)
```

or maybe the range is what you are looking

```
$test = range(1,5,2); // array(1,3,5), in arabic instead of English one,two,three
```

Comment: +1 for `$len = count($test);`

Comment: Yeah, good call; however, I think this guy needs to learn about foreach loops.

Comment: there is no difference between foreach, and for ...in fact, for is faster as it does not set the $key

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($test as $k=>$v){
echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($test as $key=>$value){
    dump("$key = $value");
}
```

Comment: your variables are wrong I think

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
foreach($test as $data) {
   $dosomethingwithdata = $data;
}
```